# git and jgit committing difference: git requires email while jgit doesn't

Tags: git, netbeans

Working on a project, i am mixing Netbeans 7.3 integrated git client (that actually is jgit) and command line git client. 
When committing with Netbeans, the IDE offers two fields: `Author` and `Committer`.

[image]

But when working on the same project via command line, i get:

```
$git commit

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'agostinox@local-pc.(none)')
```

Consistently, `git config --list` returns a set of keys that doesn't contain user.email or user.name.

It would be easy to add the information reuqired, but the question is: since the auto-detection of eamil address has failed, *which is the email address that has been used in the previous, successful commit performed by Netbeans (jgit)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see what was used is probably to look at `git log --pretty=fuller`.  Judging by the above, jgit probably allowed `agostinox@local-pc` as the email address.

BTW, the difference here is probably that git is unhappy about the email address it found  (`local-pc` is not a proper domain name).  jgit just has a different policy and accepts it.